# How do I use a JQueryMobile reflow responsive table without a THEAD?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to use JQueryMobile's responsive reflow table without a THEAD or with the THEAD taking no space. The use case is that I have some marketing material that I would like to be in two columns on wide screens, and a single column on a small screen.

Everything works great, except that it seems that JQM requires a THEAD. As a workaround, I put in blank headers (nbsp) into a THEAD, but I would like to get that wasted space back.

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/reL97/5/

If you remove the THEAD, it will break. However, I can't figure out a way to reduce the space of the THEAD. For example:

```
#movie-table thead {
    display: none;
}
```

Note: the reason why I don't just put actual headings in, is that when the reflow occurs, the headings take up valuable horizontal space. I would like these headings removed both vertically and horizontally.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/reL97/6/)**

thead is now empty:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

And the CSS removes margins/padding from the header cells and optionally changes the spacing when the screen narrows to reflow mode:

```
#movie-table thead tr th{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 35em) {
    #movie-table th{
        margin-top: 12px; /* optional spacing during reflow */
    }
}
```